# Featured Image of Video from oembed

Tags: post-thumbnails, oembed

For Wordpress, I want to auto generate thumb of the video embedded on a page using oembed? And then save it as a featured image of the post.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: oEmbed of _what_? YouTube?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed *just this* for a recent project, so here's my plugin! The code should be self-explanatory, but if there are any questions ask away.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: oEmbed Featured Image
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70752/1685
 * Description: Automatically set the featured image if an oEmbed-compatible embed is found in the post content.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: TheDeadMedic
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic
 *
 * @package oEmbed_Featured_Image
 */

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', array( 'ofi', 'init' ) );

/**
 * @package oEmbed_Featured_Image
 */
class ofi
{
    /**
     * The post thumbnail ID
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $_thumb_id;

    /**
     * The post ID
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $_post_id;

    /**
     * Sets up an instance if called statically, and attempts to set the featured
     * image from an embed in the post content (if one has not already been set).
     *
     * @param  int $post_id
     * @return object|null
     */
    public function init( $post_id )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $this ) )
            return new ofi( $post_id );

        global $wp_embed;

        $this->_post_id = absint( $post_id );

        if ( ! $this->_thumb_id = get_post_meta( $this->_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true ) ) {
            if ( $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $this->_post_id, 'raw' ) ) {

                add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );
                $wp_embed->autoembed( $content );
                remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see init()
     */
    public function __construct( $post_id )
    {
        $this->init( $post_id );
    }

    /**
     * Callback for the "oembed_dataparse" hook, which will fire on a successful
     * response from the oEmbed provider.
     *
     * @see WP_oEmbed::data2html()
     *
     * @param string $return The embed HTML
     * @param object $data   The oEmbed response
     * @param string $url    The oEmbed content URL
     */
    public function oembed_dataparse( $return, $data, $url )
    {
        if ( ! empty( $data->thumbnail_url ) && ! $this->_thumb_id ) {
            // if ( in_array( @ $data->type, array( 'video' ) ) ) // Only set for video embeds
                $this->set_thumb_by_url( $data->thumbnail_url, @ $data->title );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to download the image from the URL, add it to the media library,
     * and set as the featured image.
     *
     * @see media_sideload_image()
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $title Optionally set attachment title
     */
    public function set_thumb_by_url( $url, $title = null )
    {
        /* Following assets will already be loaded if in admin */
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';

        $temp = download_url( $url );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $temp ) && $info = @ getimagesize( $temp ) ) {
            if ( ! strlen( $title ) )
                $title = null;

            if ( ! $ext = image_type_to_extension( $info[2] ) )
                $ext = '.jpg';

            $data = array(
                'name'     => md5( $url ) . $ext,
                'tmp_name' => $temp,
            );

            $id = media_handle_sideload( $data, $this->_post_id, $title );
            if ( ! is_wp_error( $id ) )
                return update_post_meta( $this->_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $this->_thumb_id = $id );
        }

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $temp ) )
            @ unlink( $temp );
    }
}

?>
```

**Caveat:** This will only work for [registered oEmbed providers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#Can_I_Use_Any_URL_With_This.3F), and only if no [embed handler](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler) is registered for the provider (otherwise WP never makes a call to its oEmbed service).

If there are multiple embeds in a post, the first successful thumbnail grab is used.

Comment: Awesome, works a treat! Cool filter as well, `oembed_dataparse` :)

Comment: Awesome, this worked great. Thanks. Is there any way to assign same post a tag of video upon saving using the same? All though this answers my question, and works best.. why don't you publish this as plugin?

Comment: Tags aren't part of the oEmbed spec, so 'fraid not. I don't have the time to officially publish it, but anyone else is free to do so (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) & GPL).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting Question, but quoting Mike Schinkel answering a [similar Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/784/12615):

> You could hook the `save_post` action, use `WP_Http` class to
>   download it and then insert it as an attachment using
>   `wp_insert_attachment` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata()`. ***It's not
>   trivial but shouldn't be that hard.***

<sup>My emphasis.</sup>

In another Q, Milo and Chris_O [posted some useful info](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57060/12615) to deal with extracting an image URL from the content, attaching it to the post and setting it as Featured Image.

Which brings us to Kaiser's comment: what oEmbed is this?

If it is YouTube, this would be the full size thumbnail URL:
`http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBE-VIDEO-ID/0.jpg`

If Vimeo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361149/1287812

---

Instead of searching the post content each time it's updated/saved, I'd follow this approach:

#### Create a Metabox with an Input Field for the Video ID

Maybe, one input field per video hosting site. And a correspondent button "Grab thumbnail".

So, the user enters the YouTube/Vimeo video ID, press the button and we execute the side loading, attaching and featuring functions through Ajax.

In this Question ( [Unattaching images from a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54822/12615) ), I wrote a plugin that creates a metabox where an Ajax function manipulates the attachments of a post.

---

Well, this is a roadmap, feel free to expand into working code :)